# Using a canonical duplicate to close a syntax error question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

Recently I stumbled upon a question about a basic PHP syntax error.

The problem was not too hard to understand, but before any answer was posted, the question was marked as a duplicate of a wiki question:
[PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

It kind of feels like answering a question about a basic error by giving the user a book on "basic errors".

Of course, this page is a nice piece of documentation about PHP parsing and syntax errors, but I believe it should be used to complement an answer, rather than by closing a post, marking it as an "exact" duplicate of something it basically isn't.

What's your opinion on this?

Comment: If it is a simple syntax error, a comment + link to the duplicated page should be enough info to go on, right?

Answer (score 11):

The alternative to that would have been to close the question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for asking about a simple syntax error. Those are not questions we want on the site, because they have absolutely zero repeatable value to anyone else. Closing it as duplicate of an exhaustive list the user can use to troubleshoot their own code was actually the *nice* thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

It exists because these questions are asked *very* often, and posting the same answer again and again is not useful. [It's been linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/18050071?lq=1) to, either via a comment or via duplicate closure, at least 1229 times. That number excludes deleted posts.

Yes, the duplicate target contains more than 1 specific error, but that's more maintainable than splitting everything into its own question.